# Python finishes process when breakpoint is reached in external C debugger

Tags: python, c++, xcode, swig, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a c-code dynamic library written via Xcode (7-beta), and the library is wrapped as a Python (2.7.3) module. Swig (v3.0.5 --> http://www.swig.org/) is being used to do the bindings and Xcode to compile and generate the library. It's all running fine. Python is running via PyCharm (CE 4.5.3).

In order to debug the library, I do a debug build, start the module from PyCharm, go to Xcode, menu "debug->attach to process->Python" attach to the process and it works like a charm, programmer's dream (almost). The breakpoints are reached, variables read, etc.

*So here's the problem:*

While the C code is correcly halted on a breakpoint, the running script in PyCharm is finished (with exit code 0), as if it had naturally reached it's endpoint. Here's a simple situation where the problem is reproduced:

C-code (the dynamic library):

```
int TestIt(){    
    return 42;
}
```

While the Python code is basically:

```
import time
import my_c_dinamiclib

for i in range(60):
    print i, my_c_dynamiclib.TestIt()
    time.sleep(1)
```

So there are 60 seconds to attach to the process.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? I've tried running Python in debug mode, with no success.

Comment: Have you tried gcc and old-school gdb?

Comment: No I haven't. Is this an unexpected behaviour?

Comment: It is. A debugger should block the calling process